# Difference between while and a do-while code in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I'm currently learning java right now, and I looked through videos, I still don't get it, even chatgpt explains it I still do not understand, can somebody give me an brief simple explanation and an example from the while and the do-while statement?

I tried this block of code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class learn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "";
        
        while(name.isBlank()) {
            System.out.println("your name pls : ");
            name = scanner.nextLine();
            
        }
        
        System.out.println("Hello "+name);
        
        
        
    }
        
}
```

and this do while block of code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class learn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = "";
        
    do {
            System.out.println("your name pls : ");
            name = scanner.nextLine();
            
        }   while(name.isBlank());
        
        System.out.println("Hello "+name);
        
        
        
    }
        
}
```

and yet I still do not understand the difference

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) : **"The difference between do-while and while is that do-while evaluates its expression at the bottom of the loop instead of the top. Therefore, the statements within the do block are always executed at least once, as shown in the following DoWhileDemo program:"**

Comment: What about that do you not understand?

Comment: i don't understand like what is the diffy, it executes the same

Comment: with `while-do` condition is checked first, then body is executed second, with `do-while` body is executed first, condition checked second

Comment: It executes the same in this one very specific example you chosen. The difference is explained very clearly here. A do-while will execute it's block always at least once. A while loop can also chose to not execute it's block at all.

Comment: can you give a code then that demonstrates it?, for me to really see the diffy

Answer (score 2):

In While Loop, before starting the loop block it checks whether the condition provided is satisfied (true) or not. Take this example,

```
while(false){
 System.out.println("While");
}
```

on the other hand in do while, the block will be executed once before checking the condition in while. Take this as example,

```
do{
 System.out.println("Do While");
}while(false);
```

where the while loop will not print anything but the do while will print `Do While` once before checking the condition and terminating...

I hope it helps you understand that...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

If need to initialize your condition first before you being your loop, you would use `while { ... }`. If the condition is already initialized, you would use `do { ... } while` .

I like to think of it as "top test loops" and "bottom test loops", where "test" means "do I exit the loop?".

Another important difference is the bottom test loop always runs at least once. So if you need to run the code in the loop at least once, you can use a do-while.

## EDIT

@h0r53 wants an example of a while loop initializing a condition. So here are two examples:

- The Java Iterator interface must be "primed" before looping by calling "iterator.next()" This is best done with a top-test loop
  ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html
- The Java Pattern Matcher interface has `matcher.matches()`, which again, primes the loop condition. This is best done with a top test loop. ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: I don't think the difference has much to do with initializing a condition. It's more about guaranteeing a routine to execute at least once, despite the condition, versus conditionally looping.

Comment: @h0r53 that is not correct. I've added examples.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter - I'm simply stating that the primary difference between a while loop and a do-while loop is the loop condition is evaluated at the end of a do-while loop and it is evaluated at the beginning of a while loop. You may have valid examples of loops involving initialization, but that is a specific case and not a general difference between the two constructs.

Comment: Again, I'm not the downvoter. Not sure if it was you but going to random answers I've provided in the past and downvoting seems pretty petty. But as you've provided examples in an attempt to address my concerns, and those examples seem relevant here, I'll kindly provide an upvote for providing a thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will hopefully make it very clear what the difference is between a `do...while` loop and a `while` loop.

In the code below, the `safeToJump()` function will return true or false (it always returns true in this simple example) to indicate whether it is "safe to jump". If it is not safe to jump, then you will die if you still do so. With that in mind, if you `jump()` before checking if it is safe to do so, then you are gambling with your life. On the other hand, if you check to make sure it's safe before jumping, then you're guaranteed to survive:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        jump();
    } while (safeToJump());

    while (safeToJump()) {
        jump();
    }
}

public static boolean safeToJump() {
    return true;
}

public static void jump() {   
    System.out.println("Jump!");
}
```

In `main()`, in the first `do...while` loop, we are running the body of the loop BEFORE we check the conditional statement within the `while` portion, so it's possible that we jumped while conditions were not safe. This is possibly a dangerous action that could result in death. Thus, *a `do...while` loop will always run at least once before checking the conditional statement.*

In the second loop, the `while` conditional statement is checked BEFORE the body, so the `jump()` command is only executed if `true` was returned and conditions were actually safe for a jump. With that in mind, if `safeToJump()` had returned `false`, then the body of the loop would not run at all. So, *a `while` loop will run `zero or more times`.*

See the difference? Use a `do...while` loop if you want the body of the loop to run BEFORE the conditional check. Conversely, use a `while` loop if you want the body of the loop to run AFTER the conditional check.

Answer (score 0):

While loop checks the condition before executing the loop body,

```
while(condition){
   //block of statements to be executed repeatedly
}
```

Do-while loop checks the condition after executing the loop body,

```
do{
   //block of statements to be executed repeatedly
}while(condition)
```

In a while loop, the block of statements will only be executed if the condition is true.

```
while(false){
   System.out.println("Hello World");
}

output:
```

However, in a do-while loop, the block of statements inside the loop will be executed at least once, even if the condition is false.

```
do{
   System.out.println("Hello World");
}while(false)

output: Hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Only when using while, the operation starts according to the condition. But when we use the Do-While structure, it first performs the operation once and then continues according to the condition.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see how your answer adds anything that is not already stated in the other [five] answers. If you are just going to [essentially] repeat another answer, I think it is better not to answer at all.

Answer (score -1):

If you are assigning a value within the loop's conditional statement, then you may want to execute the code block first.

The following is an except from *[The C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)*, sometimes referred to as the *K&R*.
I'm using this example since *Java* inherits a majority of it's components from *C*.

This is from, *3.6 Loops–Do-while*.

> "Experience shows that *do-while* is much less used than *while* and *for*.  Nonetheless, from time to time it is valuable, as in the following function *itoa*, which converts a number to a character string (the inverse of *atoi*).  The job is slightly more complicated than might be thought at first, because the easy methods of generating the digits generate them in the wrong order.  We have chosen to generate the string backwards, then reverse it."

```c
/* itoa:  convert n to characters in s */
void itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
        n = -n;          /* make n positive */
    i = 0;
    do {       /* generate digits in reserve order */
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
```

Additionally, *Java* explains the difference with the following.

> *"The difference between do-while and while is that do-while evaluates its expression at the bottom of the loop instead of the top. Therefore, the statements within the do block are always executed at least once ..."*

*[The while and do-while Statements (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)*.